# How to know whenever the connection is reset by peer in php?

Tags: php, tcp, timeout, connection-close

I have been working lately on building a TCP server using PHP (I know wrong choice to begin with but this is the work standard), so I have reached a point where there is a reliable prototype to do tests on it and it showed good results. at start I used socket functions to handle to connection for server and it was working good but one of the main things on the project is to make the channel secured so I switched to stream_socket.

what I want is a socket_last_error equivalent in stream_socket group so I can know whenever the connection with client is closed or not. the current situation all processes will wait for timeout timer to release even tho the client is already closed.

I have searched the net and I found that there is no way to figure it out through PHP and I have found that some people opened issue ticket about it asking for socket_last_error equivalent for stream.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34380

so is there anyway to know whenever FIN_WAIT signal is raised or not?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible the `stream_socket` family, it looks like it's too high level.

I tried making a very hackish solution, I don't know if it will work for you, it's not very reliable:

```
<?php
set_error_handler('my_error_handler');

function my_error_handler($no,$str,$file,$line) {
    throw new ErrorException($str,$no,0,$file,$line);
}

$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:8000", $errno, $errstr);
if (!$socket) {
  echo "$errstr ($errno)\n";
} else {
  while ($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)) {
    foreach (str_split('The local time is ' . date('n/j/Y g:i a') . "\n") as $char) {
      echo $char;
      try {
            fwrite($conn,$char);
      } catch (ErrorException $e) {
            if (preg_match("/^fwrite\(\): send of 1 bytes failed with errno=([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z \/]+)$/",$e->getMessage(), $matches)) {
                    list($errno,$errstr) = array((int) $matches[1], $matches[2]);
                    if ($errno === 32) {
                            echo "\n[ERROR] $errstr"; // Broken pipe
                    }
            }
            echo "\n[ERROR] Couldn't write more on $conn";
            break;
      }
      fflush($conn);
    }
    fclose($conn);
  }
  fclose($socket);
}
echo "\n";
?>
```

Launch: `php ./server.php`

Connect: `nc localhost 8000 | head -c1`

Server output:

```
The loca
[ERROR] Broken pipe
[ERROR] Couldn't write more on Resource id #6
```

Comment: Thank you Janus for the answer but. as you know it is not feasible to noise the stream by sending some data to see whenever the it is broken or not also the current situation is that the server waits for client actions so with what u suggested i don't think it is feasible?